# How to use multi cultural Luis application on Azure Bot Framework?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have two luis app with multi cultural (languages) and have a bot framework webchat on the site, how can I catch browser language to use the luis app? For example if I am using the browser in German then I want to use German Luis and if English then English luis .

Answer (score 0):

Use backchannel to send navigator language to your bot and store this information in your context on the bot side.

Then use this stored information for your LUIS calls.

See this sample: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event/README.md

They are passing the navigator language in the event:

```
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
  if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
    // When we receive DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED action, we will send an event activity using WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT
    dispatch({
      type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
      payload: {
        name: 'webchat/join',
        value: { language: window.navigator.language }
      }
    });
  }
```

On your bot side, catch the info:

```
if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Event)
{
    if (turnContext.Activity.Name == "webchat/join")
    {
        // HERE, USE THE VALUE PASSED
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello dear @Nicolas R , firstly thank you for replying my post. I have added this to my bot framework .net core 2.1 default.html page . And now I am using the C# code for programming, On the Bot Framework program how can I code to catch the browsers language ? I am now using  'CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            this.language = currentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;' code but it does not catch when I changed my browser language.

Comment: I added a comment on how to catch it on the bot side

Comment: Dear @Nicolas R i am not able to catch still the browsers language! Can you help that how to do it ?

Comment: I pointed to a sample on how you should send it, and added some code on how to catch it on the bot side. Sorry but it's impossible to help more without your code here.